# Returning Value

Tags: python, function

```
def extract_info(text, price):
   company_name = ['BMW','AUDI','MERCEDES','TOYOTA']
   car_type = ['Saloon', 'Hatchback','Sedan']
   if any(word in text for word in company_name):
      for word in company_name:
         matchWord = text.split()
         if word in matchWord:
            return (word)
   elif any(word in text for word in car_type):
      for word in car_type:
        matchWord = text.split()
        if word in matchWord:
            return (word)

   else:
      productType = re.search('car', text)
      if productType is not None:
        productvalue = productType.group(0)
        return (productvalue)

  numDoor = re.search('[0-9]-door',text)
  if numDoor is not None:
        matchDoor = numDoor.group(0)
        return (matchDoor)
  else:
    return ('No match')
```

I am trying to return a value but, couldn't get all of the value . Although i am getting my output while printing them.

I was using a string "A low maintenance, 5-door car that's safe"

The code is fetching if the string get any of the word or match with regex.

Comment: The formatting seems to have got corrupted when you pasted in the code sample - For example the second line will definitely need a tab as it's part of a block. Can you edit ?

Comment: You don't have any return statements in this code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: because i was not returning any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a function can only return once.  So after line 18 :

```
    return productType
```

it return the final return of function and it will never execute after line 18. Your code after line 19 is not executing that's why you are not getting rest of result. If you want to return a bunch of output then just append in a list or use dict to save different result then return that variable at last and use that variable data as you want.

An example :

```
import re
def extract_info(text, price):
    final_output={}
    company_name = ['BMW','AUDI','MERCEDES','TOYOTA']
    car_type = ['Saloon', 'Hatchback','Sedan']
    if any(word in text for word in company_name):
        for word in company_name:
            matchWord = text.split()
            if word in matchWord:
                final_output['word']=word
    elif any(word in text for word in car_type):
        for word in car_type:
            matchWord = text.split()
            if word in matchWord:
                final_output['word']=word
    else:
        productType = re.search('car', text)
        if productType is not None:
            final_output['product_type']=productType.group(0)
    numDoor = re.search('[0-9]-door', text)
    if numDoor is not None:
        matchDoor = numDoor.group(0)
        final_output['matchdoor']=matchDoor
    else:
        final_output['matchdoor']='None'

    return final_output

print(extract_info("A low maintenance, 5-door car that's safe",23))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace print statements with return

```
if numDoor is not None:
    matchDoor = numDoor.group(0)
    return matchDoor
else:
    return 'No match'
```

Comment: i want to return to the above value too, which i had printed